# I am not able to get result from stored procedure that i created

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have created stored procedure in phpmyadmin under routines

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getData()
BEGIN
    SELECT *
        FROM register;

END
```

and i am calling it from php script as follows

```
$result=mysql_query('CALL getData()');
```

but i am not getting any data returned from stored procedure

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html where is your delimiter? http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx Example from there `DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllProducts()
   BEGIN
   SELECT *  FROM products;
   END //
DELIMITER ;`

Comment: i have given delimiter as // in delimeter box it works fine in phpmyadmin

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: So.... anything from ^

Comment: i triedt  your suggestion but no results and no errors too so what i should do?

Comment: At this point and to be honest; I don't know.

Comment: thanks for helping i am trying it on my side if i get any answer i will let u know

Comment: That would be a good thing ;-)

Comment: Ok that's how you get results from stored procedure maybe the problem is in the way you show, use result?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the mysql_* API does not have the code to retrieve stuff from a Stored Procedure.  Upgrade to mysqli_* API.